# Regex for finding everything possible (including foreign characters) between two HTML tags

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm using Regex to find the content between specific HTML tags.

However, the content may be in a foreign language and can include absolutely anything.

I am trying to figure out a regex where I can capture absolutely everything between tags. I've seen articles and Q/As on specific cases but I can't figure out how to put them all together (especially the foreign character requirement).

Does anyone have any solutions/ideas?

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser.

Comment: could you please provide some of the `html` you're talking about or what Regex have you tried so far?

Comment: see if you can find a good xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

`<.*?>` should grab anything regardless of what it could be.

Comment: Would not that match _inside_ a tag rather than _between_ tags?

Comment: Well yeah, if you mean "between" as in `>sometext<` then use the brackets the the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern to match any character but the less-than sign: `[^<]`

That will match foreign characters but not the first character of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
>.*?<
```

**Caveat**

regex is really bad for parsing HTML. Think for example about a situation where there was a '<' between two HTML tags, your regex would mess up pretty bad.

Please consider using something like **jsoup**, it's a real small library for Java that works miracles on HTML parsing.